# Why is the data from my API is not display

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Newsgenerator extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            data:{}
        }
    }
    
    
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=Apple&from=2021-06-24&sortBy=popularity&apiKey={...}")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(news => {
                this.setState({
                    data: news
                })
               
                console.log(news)
            })
    }    
    render() {
       
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.data.discription}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Newsgenerator
```

Comment: What does happen?  What is the runtime value of `news`?  Does the AJAX call succeed at all?  Please elaborate on the problem.

Comment: What's the error? What did you try? Also, the body of your message is not formatted correctly. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, just a hunch, but I don't think `discription` exists in the object retrieved by your `fetch` call.

Comment: by checking the console I am getting this                                                                        [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Newsgenerator.js:21 
{status: "ok", totalResults: 1588, articles: Array(20)}
articles: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
status: "ok"
totalResults: 1588
__proto__: Object

Comment: @HMO: Looks like that object doesn't have a `description` property.  What information are you trying to show in the component and where do you get that information?

Comment: I want to display the data I am fetching from the news API in my page. the API has an objects of articles. I probably should map trough the dat ??

Comment: @HMO: If you want to display the data that's inside of the `state.data.articles` array then, yes, you would likely use `.map()` to iterate that array in the render function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things going on here. First off, `this.state.data.discription` doesn't exist. When your API call response, you get an object like this which you set to `this.state.data`:

```js
{
  status: "ok",
  totalResults: 1588,
  articles: [...]
}
```

So `this.state.data.discription` is undefined. So what you're seeing is the result of trying to print an undefined variable - which in React is nothing.

My guess is that you want to print the articles, which means your return statement should look more like this:

```js
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.data.articles.map((article, idx) => {
      return (<h2 key={`article-${idx}`}>{article.title}</h2>)
    }}
  </div>
)
```

What you have in this code is an array of articles in your `state.data`, and you're iterating through that to print the article title (`title` in your api response).

This is the starting point and should set you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank I will work from here. appreciate you help and time to reply